# Atmega8 stops working after downloding EEPROM image

Tags: arduino, avr, eeprom

I had a very strange problem - after downloading EEPROM image to my atmega8 it's suddenly stops working - it's looks like it hangs up or something like this. If I download only flash image - it works perfect, except unproper values in EEMEM variables. I'm using avr-gcc as compiler, avrdude for uploading flash and EEPROM images thru arduino bootloader.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify what bootloader and protocol you are using? EEPROM write support is a feature that is unsupported by some bootloaders. Sending EEPROM write commands may lead to at best errors and at worse the bootloader doing _bad things_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found out what happens - I'm using optiboot and by default it has no support for EEPROM writing. It just silently writes EEPROM data into flash, breaking your program. It needs to be recompiled with BIGBOOT=1 option to work properly.